# I Want to do a loop and to exit the loop is a exit when not=

Tags: turing-lang

I try to do a loop and to exit the loop the number that you put are not the same 
EX: 1,2,3,4,5,6 (exit the loop)
Ex: 1,1,2,3,4,5 (the program ask to enter a new number)
 I try to do with not= but it dont look like it is working.

```
var theDateTime, theDate, theTime : string
var word : string
var r4 := "ok"
var n, a, r2, r3, rejouer, r : string
var c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6 : int
var n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6 : int
var code : int
var p : int := 0
var GP : int := 1
var ar, ar1 : int

loop
    put " Voulez vous jouer au 6-49 si oui entrez 'commencer' et n'oubliez pas qu'une "
    put " partie coute 3$ " ..
    get word

    %Je clear l'ecrant
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour.."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour..."
    delay (500)
    cls

    %Je fais certain que le joueur a ecrit commencer
    %Si il entre quelque choses d'autre que commencer le programme ne commence pas il demander de entre le mot commencer

    exit when word = "commencer"
end loop

%J'ai demande le nom de la personne qui joue
put " Bonjour quel est votre nom? " ..
get n

%Je clear l'ecrant
cls

%Je fait un "chargement" et il a un delay de (500) et il a un point qui apparait apres
put " Chargement en cour."
delay (500)
cls
put " Chargement en cour.."
delay (500)
cls
put " Chargement en cour..."
delay (500)
cls



put " Une partie pour jouer au 6-49 coute " ..
color (red)
put "3$"
color (black)

%Je demade au joueur avec combien d'argent qui veux jouer
put " Entrez combien d'argent que vous voulez jouer avec: " ..
color (red)
put "$" ..
get ar
color (black)

loop
    if ar <= 2 then
        cls
        put " Se montent ne peut etre utiliser "
        put " Une partie coute 3$ "
        put " Veuiller entrez un nouveau montent. " ..
        get ar
    end if
    exit when ar >= 3
end loop
cls

%Je monte le montent que le joueur a entrer
put " Voulez vous vraiment joueur avec le montent suivent? " ..
color (red)
put "$", ar ..
color (black)

%Je masur que le monten qu ele joueur a entrez est se qui voulait vraiment
put " Si oui entrez" ..
color (red)
put " 'oui' " ..
color (black)
put "et si" ..
put " vous ne vouler pas appuyer sur une autre cle. " ..
color (red)
color (black)
get r
%Je fait en sort que si le joueur a dit oui que le jeu continue et ne lui demande pas encore de entrez un montent
if r = "oui" then

    %Je fait un "chargement" et il a un delay de (500) et il a un point qui apparait apres
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour.."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour..."
    delay (500)
    cls

else
    cls
    %Je demande quel est le nouveau monetant que la personne veux
    put " Quel est le montent que vous voulez jouer avec? Une partie coute 3$ " ..

    color (red)
    put " $" ..
    get ar
    color (black)
    loop
        if ar <= 2 then
            cls
            put " Se montent ne peut etre utiliser "
            put " Une partie coute 3$ "
            put " Veuiller entrez un nouveau montent. " ..
            get ar
        end if
        exit when ar >= 3
    end loop

end if


loop
    %Je clear l'ecrant
    cls

    %Je dit se que le jouer peut ganger
    put " Avant de commencer a jouer," ..
    put " " ..
    put n ..
    put " voici les prix que vous pouvez gagner."

    %Je met un linge par decu les pris
    color (red)
    put " ======================================="
    color (black)

    put " 1 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "0$"
    color (black)
    put " 2 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "2$"
    color (black)
    put " 3 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "10$"
    color (black)
    put " 4 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "100$"
    color (black)
    put " 5 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "10 000$"
    color (black)
    put " 6 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "10 000 000$$"
    color (black)

    %Je met une line pour faire cute
    color (red)
    put " ======================================="
    color (black)

    put " "
    put " Bonne chance!!!"
    put " "
    delay (1000)

    %J'explique ce que le joueur doit faire et je demander d'entrer 6 chiffres entre 1 et 49
    put " Bonjour" ..
    put " " ..
    put n ..
    put ","
    put " "
    put " Vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put ar ..
    put "$" ..
    color (black)
    put " pour en banque."
    put " "
    %Je montre au joueur que je prend 3$ pour sa partie
    put " Une partie coute 3$"
    color (red)
    put " " ..
    put ar ..
    put " - 3 "
    put " = " ..
    put ar - 3 ..
    put "$" ..
    color (black)
    put " Se que il vous reste en banque apres le paiment pour votre partie."
    put " "

    %Je montre combien de parti que le joueur a jouer
    put " Vous etre a votre " ..
    color (red)
    put GP ..
    color (black)
    put " Parti de jouer."
    put " "

    %Je prend 3$ du la banque d'argent que il a car une partie coute 3$
    ar += -3

    %Je demander au jouer de entre ses 6 numero
    put " Pour jouer vous devez entrer 6 numeros un apres l'autre entrez un numero faite"
    put " entre entre 1 et 49."
    put " " ..
    get c1
    put " " ..
    get c2
    put " " ..
    get c3
    put " " ..
    get c4
    put " " ..
    get c5
    put " " ..
    get c6

    %Je clear l'ecrant
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour.."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour..."
    delay (500)
    cls


    %Je massure que personne met des numeros plus petit ou plus grand 1-49
    %Je fait sur que personne peut mettre un numero plus petit que un ou plus grand que 49

    %Je fait le 1er nuemro
    loop
        if c1 < 1 or c1 > 49 then

            put " Votre 1er numero est soit plus petit ou plus grand que 1 ou 49"

            %Je dit au jouereur de entrer un nouveau numero
            put " Entrer un nouveau numero " ..
            get c1

            exit when c1 >= 1 or c1 <= 49
        end if


        %Je fait le 2e nuemro
        if c2 < 1 or c2 > 49 then
            put " Votre 2e numero est soit plus petit ou plus grand que 1 ou 49"

            %Je dit au jouereur de entrer un nouveau numero
            put " Entrer un nouveau numero " ..
            get c2

            exit when c2 >= 1 or c2 <= 49
        end if

        %Je fait le 3e nuemro
        if c3 < 1 or c3 > 49 then
            put " Votre 3e numero est soit plus petit ou plus grand que 1 ou 49"

            %Je dit au jouereur de entrer un nouveau numero
            put " Entrer un nouveau numero " ..
            get c3

            exit when c3 >= 1 or c3 <= 49
        end if

        %Je fait le 4e numero
        if c4 < 1 or c4 > 49 then
            put " Votre 4e numero est soit plus petit ou plus grand que 1 ou 49"

            %Je dit au jouereur de entrer un nouveau numero
            put " Entrer un nouveau numero " ..
            get c4

            exit when c4 >= 1 or c4 <= 49
        end if

        %Je fait le 5e nuemro
        if c5 < 1 or c5 > 49 then
            put " Votre 5e numero est soit plus petit ou plus grand que 1 ou 49"

            %Je dit au jouereur de entrer un nouveau numero
            put " Entrer un nouveau numero " ..
            get c5

            exit when c5 >= 1 or c5 <= 49
        end if

        %Je fait le 6e numero
        if c6 < 1 or c6 > 49 then
            put " Votre 6e numero est soit plus petit ou plus grand que 1 ou 49"

            %Je dit au jouereur de entrer un nouveau numero
            put " Entrer un nouveau numero " ..
            get c6

            exit when c6 >= 1 or c6 <= 49
        end if

        % J'ai fait une variable qui est = a ok donc le joueur na pas a enter ok pour que le programme continue
        % Le r4 = ok est que je devait sortir de ma loop et je devait trouver une facon pour sortir sans que le joueur entre le mot ok.
        exit when r4 = "ok"
    end loop

    %Je clear l'ecrant et un chargement
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour.."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour..."
    delay (500)
    cls

    %Je faire sur que le jouer ne entre pad 2 fois le meme numero
    %Si il met 2 fois le meme numero il a un message qui arrive pour dire qui a mis deja se numero et le programme arrete
    %29/9/2019
    %Faire que si la personne entre 2 fis le meme numero sa lui dit et il peut le changer et continuer a jouer

    if c1 = c2 or c1 = c3 or c1 = c4 or c1 = c5 or c1 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
    elsif c2 = c1 or c2 = c3 or c2 = c4 or c2 = c5 or c2 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c3 = c1 or c3 = c2 or c3 = c4 or c3 = c5 or c3 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c4 = c1 or c4 = c2 or c4 = c3 or c4 = c5 or c4 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c5 = c1 or c5 = c2 or c5 = c3 or c5 = c4 or c5 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c6 = c1 or c6 = c2 or c6 = c3 or c6 = c4 or c6 = c5 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    end if

    loop
             %Je fait sur que le joueur ne mette pas deux fois le meme numero
    if c1 = c2 or c1 = c3 or c1 = c4 or c1 = c5 or c1 = c6 then
        put "Entrez un nouveau numero!"
        get c1
        exit when c1 not= c2 or c1 not= c3 or c1 not= c4 or c1 not= c5 or c1 not= c6
    end if

    if c2 = c1 or c2 = c3 or c2 = c4 or c2 = c5 or c2 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c2
        exit when c2 not= c1 or c2 not= c3 or c2 not= c4 or c2 not= c5 or c2 not= c6
        end if

        if c3 = c1 or c3 = c2 or c3 = c4 or c3 = c5 or c3 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c3
        exit when c3 = c1 or c3 = c2 or c3 = c4 or c3 = c5 or c3 = c6
        end if

        if c4 = c1 or c4 = c2 or c4 = c3 or c4 = c5 or c4 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c4
        exit when c4 not= c1 or c4 not= c2 or c4 not= c3 or c4 not= c5 or c4 not= c6
        end if

        if c5 = c1 or c5 = c2 or c5 = c3 or c5 = c4 or c5 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c5
        exit when c5 not= c1 or c5 not= c2 or c5 not= c3 or c5 not= c4 or c5 not= c6
        end if

        if c6 = c1 or c6 = c2 or c6 = c3 or c6 = c4 or c6 = c5 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c6
        exit when c6 not= c1 or c6 not= c2 or c6 not= c3 or c6 not= c4 or c6 not= c6
        end if
    end loop

    %Les numeros qui son choisi au hasard par le programme qui sont les numeros gagants
    randint (g1, 1, 49)
    randint (g2, 1, 49)
    randint (g3, 1, 49)
    randint (g4, 1, 49)
    randint (g5, 1, 49)
    randint (g6, 1, 49)

    %Je fait sur que le jeu ne donne pas 2 ou 3 fois le meme numero gagants
    if g1 = g2 or g1 = g3 or g1 = g4 or g1 = g5 or g1 = g6 then
        randint (g1, 1, 49)
    elsif g2 = g1 or g2 = g3 or g2 = g4 or g2 = g5 or g2 = g6 then
        randint (g2, 1, 49)
    elsif g3 = g1 or g3 = g2 or g3 = g4 or g3 = g5 or g3 = g6 then
        randint (g3, 1, 49)
    elsif g4 = g1 or g4 = g2 or g4 = g3 or g4 = g5 or g4 = g6 then
        randint (g4, 1, 49)
    elsif g5 = g1 or g5 = g2 or g5 = g3 or g5 = g4 or g5 = g6 then
        randint (g5, 1, 49)
    elsif g6 = g1 or g6 = g2 or g6 = g3 or g6 = g4 or g6 = g5 then
        randint (g6, 1, 49)
    end if

    %Je montre les numero gagants
    color (red)
    put " ============================================="
    color (black)

    %Je montre les numero gagants
    put " Voici les numeros gagants!"
    color (red)
    put " " ..
    put g1 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put g2 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put g3 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put g4 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put g5 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put g6
    put " "
    color (black)

    %Je met une line pour faire cute
    color (red)
    put " ============================================="
    color (black)

    %Je montre les numero de la personne a chosis
    put " Vous numeros:"
    color (red)
    put " " ..
    put c1 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put c2 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put c3 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put c4 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put c5 ..
    put " " ..
    put " " ..
    put c6
    put " "
    color (black)

    % Je fais le calcul pour les numeros qui sont pareils
    if c1 = g1 or c1 = g2 or c1 = g3 or c1 = g4 or c1 = g5 or c1 = g6 then
        p += 1
    end if
    if c2 = g1 or c2 = g2 or c2 = g3 or c2 = g4 or c2 = g5 or c2 = g6 then
        p += 1
    end if
    if c3 = g1 or c3 = g2 or c3 = g3 or c3 = g4 or c3 = g5 or c3 = g6 then
        p += 1
    end if
    if c4 = g1 or c4 = g2 or c4 = g3 or c4 = g4 or c4 = g5 or c4 = g6 then
        p += 1
    end if
    if c5 = g1 or c5 = g2 or c5 = g3 or c5 = g4 or c5 = g5 or c5 = g6 then
        p += 1
    end if
    if c6 = g1 or c6 = g2 or c6 = g3 or c6 = g4 or c6 = g5 or c6 = g6 then
        p += 1
    end if

    % Le calcul pour le prix pour le joueur
    if p = 1 then
        ar += 0
    elsif p = 2 then
        ar += 2
    elsif p = 3 then
        ar += 10
    elsif p = 4 then
        ar += 100
    elsif p = 5 then
        ar += 10000
    elsif p = 6 then
        ar += 10000000
    end if

    %Je montre ce que le joueur a eu
    put " Vouci combien de numero que vous avez eu " ..
    color (red)
    put p
    color (black)

    %Je montre combien d'argent qui lui reste
    put " Il vous reste" ..
    put " " ..
    color (red)
    put " " ..
    put ar ..
    put " $"
    put " "

    %Je met une line pour faire cute
    color (red)
    put " ============================================="
    color (black)

    %Je montre les sommes d'argent que le joueur peut gaganer
    put " 1 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "0$"
    color (black)
    put " 2 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "2$"
    color (black)
    put " 3 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "10$"
    color (black)
    put " 4 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "100$"
    color (black)
    put " 5 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "10 000$"
    color (black)
    put " 6 chiffre vous avez " ..
    color (red)
    put "10 000 000$$"
    color (black)

    %Je met une line pour faire cute
    color (red)
    put " ============================================="
    color (black)


    %J'ai un delay de 15 sec
    %Je clear l'ecrant
    delay (15000)
    cls

    %Je fais certain qui a toujours assez d'argent pour jouer
    %NE MARCHE PAS A 100% ENCORE A TRAVAILLER
    %DOIT AVOIR QUELQUE CHOSES SI LA PERSONNE NE VEUX PAS METTRE DE L'ARGENT

    %Je dit au joueur qui na pu assez d'argent pour jouer et qui peut en ajouter ou arrete de jouer
    loop

        %Si le joueur a 3$ ou plus le programme sort de la loop
        exit when ar >= 3

        %Si le joueur a moins que 3$ le programme lui demande si il veux ajouter de l'argent ou si il veux juste arreter
        if ar < 3 then
            put " "
            put " Vous n'avez pu assez d'argent pour une autre partie. Desole!"
            put " "
            put " Voulez vous rajouter de l'argent? 'oui' sinon apputer sur une 'non'. " ..
            get r3
            cls
        elsif ar >= 3 then
        end if
        exit when ar >= 3

        %Je fait un if pour savoir combien d'argent que le jouer veux mettre.
        if r3 = "oui" then
            put "Combien d'argent voulez vous ajouter? $" ..
            get ar

        elsif r3 = "non" then
            cls
            put " Passer une bonne journee "
            put " Merci d'avoir jouer au 6-49 "

        end if

        %Je fait que si le joueur a dit sa sort de la loop ou si il a mis 3$ ou plus pour poursuivre a jouer
        exit when r3 = "oui"
        exit when r3 = "non"

    end loop

    %Mon if est que si la personne dit quelle ne veux pas ajouter de l'argent et dit non sa sort du loop mais le jeux s'arrete pas
    %if r3 (Reponse de la question si veux ajouter de l'argent) est non then le jeux arrete il ne va pas plus loin il ss'arrete
    if ar >= 3 then
        %r3 = "oui"
    end if

    if r3 = "oui" then

    elsif r3 = "non" then
        exit
    end if

    %Je demander si la personne veux jouer encore
    put " Voulez vous jouer encore? 'Oui' pour continuer ou 'non' pour arreter."



    %J'ai fait que si tu met o sa recommence le jeu
    %Je demander si le joueur veux jouer encore ou pas
    put " " ..
    get rejouer
    cls

    %Je fait sur que le c'est toujours la meme personne qui joue et que il n'on pas changer et qui veux encore jouer
    if rejouer = "oui" then

        put " Est-ce que ces toujours vous " ..
        put n ..
        put " si oui entrez 'oui' si se n'est pas vous entrez un autre touche."
        get r

        %Je fait sur que si c'est le meme joueur que sa ne reste pas et que si c'est un nouveau joueur le jeux se reste
        if r = "oui" then

            %Je fait un "chargement" et il a un delay de (500) et il a un point qui apparait apres
            cls
            put " Chargement en cour."
            delay (500)
            cls
            put " Chargement en cour.."
            delay (500)
            cls
            put " Chargement en cour..."
            delay (500)
            cls

            %Je fait +1 au nombre de parti jouer par le joueur
            GP += 1

        else
            %Je demand le nom du jouer qui commencecr a jouer
            put " Quel est votre nom?"
            get n

            %Je remet le nombrede parti jouer a 1
            GP := 1

            %Je retir se qui a l'ecrant
            cls

            %Je demande avec combien d'argent que le joueur veux jouer
            put " Une partie pour jouer au 6-49 coute " ..
            color (red)
            put "3$"
            color (black)
            put " Entrez combien d'argent que vous voulez jouer avec: " ..
            color (red)
            put "$" ..
            get ar
            color (black)
            cls

            %Je monte le montent que le joueur a entrer
            put " Voulez vous vraiment joueur avec le montent suivent? " ..
            color (red)
            put "$", ar ..
            color (black)

            %Je masur que le monten qu ele joueur a entrez est se qui voulait vraiment
            put " Si oui entrez" ..
            color (red)
            put " 'oui' " ..
            color (black)
            put "et " ..
            put " si vous ne vouler pas appuyer sur une autre cle. " ..
            color (red)
            get r
            color (black)

            %Je fait en sort que si le joueur a dit oui que le jeu continue et ne lui demande pas encore de entrez un montent
            if r = "oui" then

                %Je fait un "chargement" et il a un delay de (500) et il a un point qui apparait apres
                cls
                put " Chargement en cour."
                delay (500)
                cls
                put " Chargement en cour.."
                delay (500)
                cls
                put " Chargement en cour..."
                delay (500)
                cls

            else
                cls
                %Je demande quel est le nouveau monetant que la personne veux
                put " Quel est le montent que vous voulez jouer avec? Une partie coute 3$ " ..
                color (red)
                put " $" ..
                get ar
                color (black)
            end if
        end if

        %Si la reponse est non que le joueur ne veux pu jouer le jeux arrete
    elsif rejouer = "non" then

        %FAIRE QUE LE JEUX TROUVE QUEL HEUR QUI EST ET SI
        % IL EST 18H OU PASSER 18H QUE SA DIT BONNE SOIREE
        % IL EST 12H AM A 11H SA DIT BON MATIN
        % IL EST 11H01 A 12H SA DIT BONNE AVANT MIDI
        % IL EST 12H01 A 17H59 BONNE APRES MIDI

        % theDateTime := Time.Date
        % theDate := theDateTime (1 .. 9)
        % theTime := theDateTime (11 .. *)
        % put "Greetings!!  The date and time today is ", Time.Date

        %Je fait que le programme dit bon soir apre 18h
        if theTime = "18 : 00 : 00" then

            put "Passe une bonne soiree"

        elsif
                theTime = "12 : 00 : 01" then
            put "Passe une bonne apres-midi"
        end if

        %put " Passer une bonne journee!"
        put " Merci d'avoir jouer"
        exit
    end if



    %Je remet a 0 les points
    p := 0

end loop
```

Here is here and what I have for my loop and all that

```
 if c1 = c2 or c1 = c3 or c1 = c4 or c1 = c5 or c1 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
    elsif c2 = c1 or c2 = c3 or c2 = c4 or c2 = c5 or c2 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c3 = c1 or c3 = c2 or c3 = c4 or c3 = c5 or c3 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c4 = c1 or c4 = c2 or c4 = c3 or c4 = c5 or c4 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c5 = c1 or c5 = c2 or c5 = c3 or c5 = c4 or c5 = c6 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    elsif c6 = c1 or c6 = c2 or c6 = c3 or c6 = c4 or c6 = c5 then
        put " Vous avez mis deux fois le meme numero!"
        exit
    end if

    loop
              %Je fait sur que le joueur ne mette pas deux fois le meme numero
    if c1 = c2 or c1 = c3 or c1 = c4 or c1 = c5 or c1 = c6 then
        put "Entrez un nouveau numero!"
        get c1
        exit when c1 not= c2 or c1 not= c3 or c1 not= c4 or c1 not= c5 or c1 not= c6
    end if

    if c2 = c1 or c2 = c3 or c2 = c4 or c2 = c5 or c2 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c2
        exit when c2 not= c1 or c2 not= c3 or c2 not= c4 or c2 not= c5 or c2 not= c6
        end if

        if c3 = c1 or c3 = c2 or c3 = c4 or c3 = c5 or c3 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c3
        exit when c3 = c1 or c3 = c2 or c3 = c4 or c3 = c5 or c3 = c6
        end if

        if c4 = c1 or c4 = c2 or c4 = c3 or c4 = c5 or c4 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c4
        exit when c4 not= c1 or c4 not= c2 or c4 not= c3 or c4 not= c5 or c4 not= c6
        end if

        if c5 = c1 or c5 = c2 or c5 = c3 or c5 = c4 or c5 = c6 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c5
        exit when c5 not= c1 or c5 not= c2 or c5 not= c3 or c5 not= c4 or c5 not= c6
        end if

        if c6 = c1 or c6 = c2 or c6 = c3 or c6 = c4 or c6 = c5 then
        put "Enter un nouveau numero!"
        get c6
        exit when c6 not= c1 or c6 not= c2 or c6 not= c3 or c6 not= c4 or c6 not= c6
        end if
    end loop
```

that is my code it is long I know and it is all in French I'm sorry. the game is the 6-49 
Thx for the help

Comment: Which programming language is this? [turing-machines] refers to Turing Machines in general, not a specific *type* of Turing Machine.

Comment: It is turing version 4.1.1